# Grid container inside of the cell of another grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hello fellow developers.
I am building small web project. I am trying to practice grid css system. My current problem is using grid inside the grid cell.

This is my html. "grid-container" class is my main grid. The biggest block of my website gonna be in that grid cells.
Class profile is part of the cell grid-container. I am trying to make profile cell also have a grid inside it.

```
<!-- <body>
<div class= "grid-container">
    <div class="headderItem">headder will be here</div>
    <div class="profile">
        <img id="profilePic" src="pic/profilePic.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="bio"> 
            <p>Here is text Bio</p>
        </div>
        <div class="twit">
            <p>here gonna be the last twit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        Here gonna be main staff

    </div>  
    <div class="footer">Footer is here</div>
</div>

</body> -->
```

Here my CSS and how i tried to do it:

```
 .grid-container{
    display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 100%;
     grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}
.headderItem{
    grid-column: 1 1;
    grid-row: 1 1;
    text-align: center;

}
.profile{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;  
}
#profilePic{
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    grid-column-start: : 1; 
    grid-column-end:  1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;
}
#bio{grid-column-start: : 2; 
    grid-column-end:  2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;

}
.twit{
    grid-column-start: : 1; 
    grid-column-end:  2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;

}
```

Ass you see in profile class i added second grid

```
.profile{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    /*SECOND GRID  */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;  
}
```

I have 2 columns and 2 rows
inside of those columns and rows i put 3 items

```
#profilePic{
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    grid-column-start: : 1; 
    grid-column-end:  1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;
}
#bio{grid-column-start: : 2; 
    grid-column-end:  2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;

}
.twit{
    grid-column-start: : 1; 
    grid-column-end:  2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;

}
```

Two items share the first row. One item  takes whole second row.
The problem is I get 3 columns instead of 2, when i am inserting items in the cells.
Where third column coming from and how do i delete it ?

[image: 3 columns even tho i put 2 when i set up the grid]

Comment: There are some mismatching names like "headderItem". Check it please.

Comment: Thank you very much for noticing it. I corrected it but I still have same issue

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to understand why css creates 3d row. I decide to use flex box instead of nested grid.
I created new divs to separate  **#profilePic**, **#bio** from **.twit** class. Div that has **#profilePic,** **#bio** displays content inline. And container that have both divs displays it in block. Therefore, I got the look I wanted.

```
<div class="profile">
            <div id="profileItems">
                <div id="picAndBio">
                    <img id="profilePic" src="pic/profilePic.jpg" alt="">
                    <div id="bio"> 
                        <p>Here is text about my  Bio</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="twit">
                    <p>here gonna be the last twit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
#picAndBio{
    display: inline-flex;
}
```